# QTP - Controlling if a date is later than another one

Tags: string, date, testing, qtp

Hello everyone! 
I'm writing a lot of scripts these days at work but now I'm stuck... 
Basically I need to analyze a parameter (a String) and see if the date it contains is later than another one... 
I know it could be a "nooby" question, but the fact that the parameter is a string and the control is on a date totally confuses me...

Is it something as simple as: if parameter("DataAct") > 01/01/2010 ?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at DateDiff function:  http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_datediff.asp.  Example:

```
diff = DateDiff("d", "02/19/2015", "02/20/2015") ' difference in days
diff = DateDiff("h", "02/19/2015", "02/20/2015") ' difference in hours
diff = DateDiff("n", "02/19/2015", "02/20/2015") ' difference in mins
diff = DateDiff("s", "02/19/2015", "02/20/2015") ' difference in seconds
```

To calculate the difference, you would need to parse out the date from the string and use DateDiff.

The order of dates determines the output. In the example above, all values will be positive. If you revert them, output would result in negative. Providing the same date/time will result in 0.

```
diff = DateDiff("d", "02/20/2015", "02/19/2015") ' output = -1
diff = DateDiff("d", "02/20/2015", "02/20/2015") ' output = 0
```

Comment: Nice solution. 
Turned out that doing something like "DataVar > 01/01/2015" works but your solution is more elegant so I used it. 
Thanks!